# Timer, or Handler for capturing data at regular intervals in Android mobile apps?

Tags: android, timer, handler, accelerometer

I am writing an Android app that uses the accelerometer to record captured data at regular time intervals and store them into SQLite.

Is is better to use `Timer` (and `TimerTask`), or `Handler` for this task?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a `Handler` in a `TimerTask`. Then I would use this task with a `Timer`.

Comment: Handler in a TimerTask? How would one go about that?

Comment: Handler is for the case you may have to change the UI. For your case, it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use a `Handler`. How are you recording the data?

Comment: Just simply creating a row in a table when it is time to take a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Handler is right way not timertask....You can directly use it for view invalidation not timer task